BPY set attribute
I'm trying to find out how to use bpy.ops.mesh.attribute_set() for specific attribute without the need to select it.
Right now, the code creates popup window for the selected attribute. In the end I need to create 3 buttons in N panel with attributes - POS, CarSeed and MaSeed.
Or is there a way to place a slider with the value right in the panel without the need for popup?


This is a rather straightfoward solution, it doesn't display all attributes at once as this would need create some kind of logic to initalize a collection property, but you can add that at a later point. This adds a panel in the mesh interface besides the Attributes panel. When you click on an attribute, a field displays the value you can set. Note this does NOT update when you click on a new attribute, however once you input a value it will set the attribute on the whole domain to that value. As it stands it supports, float, int, float vector and float color.
import bpy


def get_bmesh_domain(domain):
    if domain == "POINT":
        return "verts"
    elif domain == "EDGE":
        return "edges"
    elif domain == "FACE":
        return "faces"


def get_layer_type(data_type):
    if data_type == "FLOAT":
        return "float"
    elif data_type == "INT":
        return "int"
    elif data_type == "STRING":
        return "string"
    elif data_type == "FLOAT_VECTOR":
        return "float_vector"
    elif data_type == "FLOAT_COLOR":
        return "float_color"
    elif data_type == "BOOLEAN":
        return "int"
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Data type '{data_type}' not supported")


def update_attribute(fields, context, data_type, value_name):
    obj = context.object
    mesh = obj.data
    value = getattr(fields, data_type)
    if not hasattr(context, "attribute"):
        return
    attribute = context.attribute
    if context.object.mode == "OBJECT":
        if value_name == "value":
            attribute.data.foreach_set(value_name, [value for _ in range(len(attribute.data))])
        else:
            values = [value for _ in range(len(attribute.data))]
            attribute.data.foreach_set(value_name, [value for vector in values for value in vector])
        mesh.update()
    else:
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
        attribute_name = attribute.name
        domain = getattr(bm, get_bmesh_domain(attribute.domain))
        layer_type = getattr(domain.layers, get_layer_type(attribute.data_type))
        layer = layer_type.get(attribute_name)
        if isinstance(value, str):  # Strings are stored as byte strings.
            value = value.encode("utf-8")
        for item in domain:
            if item.select:
                item[layer] = value
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)



class AttributeSetField(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    FLOAT: bpy.props.FloatProperty(update=lambda self, context: update_attribute(self, context, "FLOAT", "value"))
    INT: bpy.props.IntProperty(update=lambda self, context: update_attribute(self, context, "INT", "value"))
    FLOAT_VECTOR: bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
        update=lambda self, context: update_attribute(self, context, "FLOAT_VECTOR", "vector")
    )
    FLOAT_COLOR: bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
        subtype="COLOR",
        size=4,
        min=0,
        soft_max=1,
        update=lambda self, context: update_attribute(self, context, "FLOAT_COLOR", "color"),
    )


class GU_PT_attribute_set(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Attribute Set"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "data"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        if context.object.type != "MESH":
            layout.label(text="Please select a MESH object", icon="ERROR")
        elif context.object.mode in ("OBJECT", "EDIT"):
            attribute = context.object.data.attributes.active
            row = layout.row(align=True)
            row.label(text=attribute.name)
            row.context_pointer_set("attribute", attribute)
            row.prop(context.scene.my_attribute_set_field, attribute.data_type, text="")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AttributeSetField)
    bpy.utils.register_class(GU_PT_attribute_set)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_attribute_set_field = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=AttributeSetField)



Thanks, this is a progress for me. One thing I forgot to mention is that I need it to work in edit mode for selected verts only.

@TobiášPisarovič see my updated answer
